# How to use Kubernetes SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I am trying to build an HTTPs proxy server in front of another service in Kubernetes, using either an NginX proxy LoadBalancer server, or Ingress.  Either way, I need a certificate and key so that my external requests get authenticated.

I'm looking at [how to manage tls in a cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/), and I've noticed that the certificate used to connect to the container cluster is the same one as is mounted at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt` on a running pod.

So I'm thinking that my node cluster already has a registered certificate, all I need is the key, throw it into a secret and mount that into my proxy server.  But I can't find how.

Is it this simple?  How would I do that?  Or do I need to create a new certificate, sign it etc etc?  Would I then need to replace the current certificate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an external request to get into your K8s cluster then this is the job of an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress), or configuring the service with a loadbalancer, if your cloud provider supports it.

The certificate discussed in [your reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) is really meant to be used for intra-cluster communications, as it says:

> Every Kubernetes cluster has a cluster root Certificate Authority (CA). The CA is generally used by cluster components to validate the API server’s certificate, by the API server to validate kubelet client certificates, etc.

If you go for an ingress approach then [here is the doc for tls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls). At the bottom a list of [alternatives](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#alternatives), such as the [load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer) approach.

I guess you could use the internal certificate externally if you are able to get all your external clients to trust it. Personally I'd probably use [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego), which automates getting certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), since most browsers trust this CA now.

Hope this helps